# How do I check if element is in viewport?

Tags: jquery, notifications

I am trying to implement a notifications system into my website. I've taken the ideas from http://www.red-team-design.com/cool-notification-messages-with-css3-jquery (Don't worry it's extremely simple) and I've altered it slightly to fit with my system.

My situation is that I am using one of the divs, `'.info'` to be exact for every time a new message has been sent to this user. I've set it up so far so it every time a user clicks on the page the notifications is moved out of the viewport.

```
$(document).on('click',function()
{
    hideAllNotifications();
});
```

However, I do not want this to happen when a new message is received because a user might not have noticed that the notification appeared so it should be persistent until `'.info'` is pressed i.e. when the user clicks on the .info banner. However if the user clicks on the body while this `.info` is in view then it should still be there. On the other hand, if all the other notification divs such as `.success, .error` is visible then clicking the body should just hide those divs.

How then do I implement this? I have been trying to check if info is in viewport with offset(), position() and height() but they are inconsistent.

I've tried:

```
if(($('.info').position().top < 0))
{
    $(document).on('click',function()
    {
        hideAllNotifications();
    });
//      alert("info is out of view");
}
else
{
    $('.info').on('click',function()
    {
        hideAllNotifications();
    });
//      alert("info is inside our view");
}
```

This is my function to get new messages on page refresh:

```
function getNewMessage()
{
    //retrieve new messages
    showNotification('info', 'You have a new message');
}
```

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport